# Empty string is not being matched in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have many documents with `uID:`. To query those documents, I am querying as below -

```
'query': {
           'term':  {
               'uID': ''
             }
    }
```

But it is fetching no documents. Why it is not throwing any document? Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: You have to make sure that ,your uID is indexed as `keyword` ,otherwise elastic will do a full text search

Comment: @Shubh Thanks, is there other way to query if uID isn't indexed as `keyword`?

Comment: See this -https://discuss.elastic.co/t/query-for-an-empty-string/83070

Answer (score 1):

Even with the default analyzer you can do this kind of search: use a script filter, which is slower but can handle the empty string:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:3000/_search' -d 
{
 "query": {
   "filtered": {
     "filter": {
       "script": {
         "script": "term. uID.length() == 0"
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

It will return the document with empty string as _content without a special mapping

As pointed by @js_gandalf, this is deprecated for ES>5.0. Instead you should use: query->bool->filter->script as in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

```
q=!(yourfield.keyword:"")
```

Please refer below link for more information.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax

Comment: Thanks. And I checked with query->...->script but no avail. BTW, where did @js_gandalf point this?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax
Please refer this link for more information. I've updated my answer, please refer again.